# Selection of text inside div is shown outside the div

Tags: html, css, selection

I want the user to select text (html) inside a div. However doing that will show the selection background in the browser also outside the div.

I can prevent that with (see http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/aWbgT/)

```
div { overflow: hidden; }
```

Is that the way to do it? Or, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a display: inline-b

```
div { overflow: hidden; display:inline-block; }
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aWbgT/2/)**

Comment: Thanks, that was interesting. Why does `display:inline-block` make the selection background display disappear outside the div? (Not that I understand why `overflow:hidden` work that way either, but it is a bit more easy to guess... ;-) )

Comment: @Leo `overflow:hidden` does what it says: it hides everything outside the dimensions of the box. To understand `display:inline-block`, you must understand `display:block`: in simple terms, `block` takes up the objects height across the whole width of the container. `inline-block` removes the whole-width default and forces the element to occupy only the defined width and height. As such, you will only see the selection occupy the box.

Comment: Thanks @Shiazure, both these are good mnemonics, but the rules are still far away from me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the CSS property :

```
xoverflow: hidden;
```

instead of

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Updated JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aWbgT/3/

Comment: Thanks, but it was not a typo. I just left it that way so it was easier to test. ;-)

Comment: oh ok ! So Juan C.'s answer (`inline-block`) seems to be a good alternative.

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand it. ;-)